# How can i disable jtable row sorter

Tags: java, swing

I Applied a row sorter to `JTable`, Table retrieves too many records and when the user clicks on table header to sort the special field, it causes a problem and the Application crashes.
I would like to disable sort when the table hasn't loaded completely! How can I do that?

Comment: apply the sorter only after the table is completely loaded. Or consider using JXTable and its enhanced rowSorter which have a sortable property to disable user-triggered sorting of all columns (vs. plain core sorter which allows to disable sorting per column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
```

Unless the `TableRowSorter` is set somewhere, I don't think that you have to call `setRowSorter(null)`

Comment: `false` is the default value for a plain table's autocreate property, so there's no need to explicitly set it. Furthermore, it doesn't disable the sorting temporarily ... which seems to be the OP's actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

try calling the method "setRowSorter" with a null parameter.
It should disable all sorting in 1.6 (and hopefully, also in 1.7).